# How do I install python libraries on Android to run a Flask server hosted code

Tags: python, android, flask, libraries

I've written a deep learning model, and I need to create an app with a Python backend. For the frontend, I've decided to use Flutter because I am already familiar with it, but I need to import some libraries in the Python module running on a Flask locally hosted server on Android in the backend, and I don't know how to install the libraries on a phone that an end-user can just download the app from Google Play and not care.

Just for clarisifation I need this libraries:

> flask, socket, threading, time and paramiko

although some of them are python built-in